# automatic testing / infeasibility detection of two-phases SIMPLEX method

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

this is the part II of my adventure in the world of the SIMPLEX method (previous episode [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839701/selection-of-pivotal-elements-in-simplex-method)).

Thanks to the suggestions I got, I could implement the two-phases SIMPLEX method to deal with problems in the form

$\max f = c^T x $

s.t.

$A x \leq b$

$A_{eq} x = b_{eq} $

$x_i \geq 0$, $\forall i$

To test the routine I created a function which generates (what I thought were) feasible LPs. The procedure is the following.

- First, generate a positive number $n$ (number of variables), a positive number $l$ representing the equality constraints, and a positive number $m$ representing the inequality constraints, with the conditions that

$l \cong n/3$, 
$m \cong n/3$

- Generate a positive vector $ x \in \mathbb R^n$
- Generate a random matrix $ A \in R^{l \times n}$
- Compute the vector $ b \in R^{l \times 1}$ as 
  $b = A x + \tilde b$, with $\tilde b = round(rand([0,1]))$ 
  such that $A x \leq b$ is satisfied (some with equality sign, some with strict inequality)
- Generate a random matrix $ A_{eq} \in R^{m \times n}$
- Evaluate the vector $ b_{eq} \in R^{m \times 1}$ as $A_{eq}x$ equality constraints are also satisfied.
- Generate a cost function $f \in \mathbb R^n$ with all positive or null elements.

  - if $f^T x > 0 $ assign $f = -f$

Most of the times it works, but I don't have yet implemented infeasibility detection.  So, first, is this procedure fair? to me it seems that all the constraints are satisfied.

and how can I detect infeasibility at the end of phase I of the SIMPLEX method? I noticed that in some final tableaus the RHS elements associated to some basic variables are negative, which sounds like an infeasibility detection. Is this true? how can I detect infeasibility / unboundness? I suspect there is still something weird as the problem

$\max p = -0.5116x_1  -  0.9847x_2 -   0.6619x_3 -   0.4476x_4  -  0.9183x_5$

subject to

$  0.3417x_1  + 0.4581x_2 +  0.3819x_3 + 0.9788x_4 + 0.1806x_5 \leq 12.2376$
$ -0.2736x_1  + 0.1504x_2 - 0.4258x_3  + 0.1067x_4 + 0.1062x_5 =   1.2023$
$ -0.4892x_1  - 0.2337x_2 - 0.2130x_3  + 0.9547x_4 - 0.1664x_5 =   7.3083$

is feasible, with solution

$x_1 = 0, x_2 = 2.18392, x_3 = 0, x_4 = 8.18967, x_5 = 0$, but I get a non-sense solution

$x_1 = -10.0357, x_2 = -10.2668, x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = 0$.

What other checks can I implement to make sure I get positive, meaningful solutions?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @LinAlg your expertise is of course more than welcome!

Comment: and the same holds for you @callculus

Comment: look at the test cases Hans Mittelman uses

Comment: obviously your procedure generates a feasible problem; infeasibility is when you cannot remove  the artificial variables from the basis; your non-sense solution has negative values, check the iteration in which you introduce these

Comment: U're right. it happens when I start to kick out the artificial variables. If the coefficient I pivot around is negative the RHS begins to have negative values.

Comment: LP solvers don't use artificial variables. They use a single slack (implicitly) for each row. Infeasibility is easily checked by comparing basic variables against their bounds. In that case a phase 1 iteration is performed. Anyway, you probably should study a bounded revised simplex method. That is what is being used in practice.

Comment: @LinAlg do you know what the criteria to select the ordering of removal of artifiicial variables are during phase I?

Comment: @venom they are just regular simplex iterations

Comment: I though it, but if I look at the coefficients of the augmented cost function to determine the pivot elements I don't get rid of the artificial variables, do I?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen thanks! I think later on I'll switch to something like that!

Comment: @LinAlg now everything works. Thanks a lot! the note you sent me explained how to deal with degenerate pivots, that was what was missing!